# Message filtering in SQS Sensor On Airflow

Tags: airflow

Unable to do message filtering of messages present in a sqs queue using SqsSensor on Airflow.

```
Sample json
"messages" : "[{'Body': '{"Records":[{"s3":{"object":{"key":"dummy.txt"}}}]}'}]"
```

I tried the below snippet, but message filtering is not working. (Airflow version 2.4.3)

```
sqs_test = SqsSensor(
        task_id='sqs_test',
        sqs_queue=queue_url,
        wait_time_seconds=0,
        max_messages=10,
        num_batches=3,
        dag=dag,
        message_filtering='jsonpath',
        message_filtering_match_values= ['dummy.txt'],
        message_filtering_config= 'messages.Body[*]',
    )
```

Also if I want to have custom message_filtering not literal or jsonpath,
How to do it ?